# Free movie website scripts

Tags: php, cms, free, looking-for-a-script

Is there any free "movie website" script/code in PHP?

I don't want video sharing ones like this: http://www.phpmotion.com/

I just want something to manage and display a database of movies.  Like forfreemovie.com (but this is paid one).

thanks

Comment: Have you tried Easymoviesscript.com yet?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that to my knowledge. I try to keep informed with many open source script options. You could buy replica of the site forfreemove.com at Easymoviescript.com.